# Python namedtuple: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'end_pos'

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I have a class that starts as follows:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Parser:
    Rule = namedtuple('Rule', ['lhs', 'rhs', 'dot_pos', 'start_pos', 'end_pos'])

    # __init__ ...
```

Since PyCharm detected all my tuple element namings correctly by giving me proper suggestions, I assumed I did it the right way so far, creating a little `Rule` class with the syntax shown above.

Now, I have a method within my `Parser` class that takes a `Rule` parameter:

```
def add(self, dot_rule: Rule):
    print(dot_rule.end_pos)
    # ...
```

Unfortunately, following error appears as soon as I try to call an element of `dot_rule` like `end_pos`:

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'end_pos'`

What is it that I misunderstood when using `namedtuple`?

**Edit:** I call the method `add` the following way with `lhs`, `rhs`, and `pos` being some values calculated beforehand:

`self.add((lhs, rhs, 0, pos, pos))`

I thought since `namedtuple` is said to be backward-compatible with `tuple` this would be the correct syntax. Apparently, the parameter is now seen as a plain `tuple` instead of a `Rule`. What can I do differently here?

**Edit 2:** Traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\earley.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "...\earley.py", line 14, in main
    parser = Parser(grammar, lexicon, sentence)
  File "...\parser.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.parse(sentence)
  File "...\parser.py", line 56, in parse
    self.predict('S', i)
  File "...\parser.py", line 41, in predict
    self.add((lhs, rhs, 0, pos, pos))  # (X -> .α, i, i)
  File "...\parser.py", line 24, in add
    print(dot_rule.end_pos)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'end_pos'
```

Comment: You apparently passed something to `.add()` that is a plain tuple, rather than a `Rule`.  You haven't shown us the code where the method is actually called, and that parameter to it is created.  (The full traceback message would have shown exactly where that was, but you didn't show that either.)

Comment: Type annotating the parameter doesn't automatically make it a namedtuple when a normal tuple is passed

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the suggestion, I added the moment `.add()` is called. And you are right of course, I obviously passed a plain `tuple`. What can I do instead here?

Comment: @jasonharper Added the traceback message, too. Hope the question is more informative now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: essentially you were passing it a class tuple instead of the *namedtuple* called Rule. See:

**Instead of** `self.add((lhs, rhs, 0, pos, pos))`

**Use** `self.add(Parser.Rule(lhs, rhs, 0, pos, pos))`

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I think I misunderstood the idea of the backwards compatibility of `namedtuple`. Both `Parser.Rule(lhs, rhs, 0, pos, pos)` and `self.Rule(lhs, rhs, 0, pos, pos)` seem to work equally well, by the way. Would be interesting to know if there is any real difference between these variations.